# How to give a Openshift container's unprivileged user read access to /root/.ssh for spring cloud config server SSH authentication?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, spring-cloud

I want to use SSH Authentication with Spring boot cloud config server.  Up to now, I've been running the config server in a docker container on docker swarm with no issues.

My organization recently decided to move everything to Openshift 3.  I am trying to get the config server deployed however I'm running into issues authenticating to Gitlab using SSH.  In the docker image, I used before I just copied the public and private SSH keys into /root/.ssh and it worked but it's not working at all in my Fabric8 generated S2I image on Openshift.

In Openshift I created a generic kubernetes secret called `cfgssh` which consists of the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys (base64 encoded)
I then mounted the secret to /root/.ssh in my deployment config/containers.  This doesn't work I'm guessing as to the user that the application is run as doesn't have read access to /root/.ssh?  This always ends up in configServer crashing after an auth exception.

I am able to run spring cloud configserver locally and on docker swarm without any auth issues so it's definitely not a cloud configserver config issue.

Has anyone else encountered/found a way around this?

My config is below.

Maven fabric8 deployment fragment:

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    spec:      
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: qa
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cfgssh
              mountPath: ~/.ssh
              readOnly: true
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTPS
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTPS
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTIONS
              value: "-Xms64M -Xmx256M"
      volumes:
        - name: cfgssh
          secret:
            secretName: cfgssh
            items:              
              - key: id_rsa
                path: id_rsa
              - key: id_rsa.pub
                path: id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's using the ssh client in the container (you didn't specify the image that you are using), my guess is that whatever user that you are running as is not `root`. You can just check what the default user is for the container by exec-ing into it

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -c <container-name> sh
$ whoami
```

Having said that, mounting on `~/.ssh` should work (you check when you exec into the pod/container). So I think you might have the wrong permissions for your `id_rsa` file. (They need to be `0600`). Make sure of that in your `volumes` section:

```yaml
      volumes:
        - name: cfgssh
          secret:
            secretName: cfgssh
            defaultMode: 0600 <= add this
            items:              
              - key: id_rsa
                path: id_rsa
              - key: id_rsa.pub
                path: id_rsa.pub
```

Reference: [secrets file permissions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-files-permissions).

Comment: it's a centos7 container

When I run whoami in a debug session I get 
-4.2$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1001800000
sh-4.2$


When I run ls -l on root I get
-4.2$ ls -l root
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root 3302 May 31 


I looked at the idrsa and id_rsa.pub files and permissions looked OK, rwxrwxrwx...

Any further ideas on how I can debug this?

Comment: If those files are under `/root`/ consider adding a securityContext to force it to run your containers/pod as root.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/.  Basically, `runAs: 0` . Although something better would be to try to use a completely different user (non-root) for security reasons.

Comment: If you run as non-root your id_rsa and id_rsa.pub must be under `/home/youruser/.ssh`

Comment: so I had a look at the fabric8 S2i builder image and I see that the user is user 1000.  When I run cd ~ in a debug session and I run pwd I end up at / so JGit still isn't able to access my SSH keys...

Comment: I also mounted the keys to /home/1000 but still no luck...